# 'Operator > cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'object' and a right hand side of type 'object' error in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have these code in unity and I've received this error. "Operator > cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'object' and a right hand side of type 'object'.  For me it's like a bug in the game engine's unityscript, what do you think??

```
var PlayerNames = ["john","doe","potato"];
var PlayerScores = [3,2,5];

if(PlayerScores[1] < PlayerScores[0])
print("potato");
```

Comment: It is valid javascript. You can even compare objects in javascript.

Comment: @JanDvorak but it doesn't work in unity. its driving me nuts.

Comment: Isn't this a syntax error somewhere before this code?

Comment: @JanDvorak nothing.. 'coz if i don't use those arrays for comparison, i dont get that error message.

Comment: @JanDvorak its fine now, Ive just made two new temporary variables and i assigned those arrays to it so i'll compare those two created variables.. and it worked. maybe its really a bug.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between UnityScript and Javascript. In JavaScript, there is no need to call your variables to a class. Therefore, the code you showed us is correct.

However, this is incorrect in UnityScript. You need to declare the classes of the variables. See this example:

```
function Machine(x) {
   this.kind = ["bulldozer", "lathe", "car"][x];
}

var c = new Machine(2);
print(typeof c.announce); // "undefined"

Machine.prototype.announce = function() {
   print("I am a "+this.kind+".");
};

print(typeof c.announce); // "function"
c.announce(); // prints "I am a car."
```

As shown above, in JavaScript, a function can create an object, when called with the new keyword. After that happens, the prototype (template) object Machine can be extended to provide additional functionality, and all class instances, past and future, are affected by this extension.

UnityScript has classes, unlike JavaScript. Also, in UnityScript, once you've defined a class, that class is more or less fixed for the duration of the runtime of your program. (N.B. There may be some exceptions to this rule, such as Reflection, but you probably do not need this and should not be using it because it's not very efficient.) However, the class system has the added benefit of being an easier-to-read, more familiar (to most) language.

```
class Machine {
   var kind : String; // fields are public by default
   function Machine(x : int) {
      this.kind = ["bulldozer", "lathe", "car"][x];
   }

   function announce() {
      print("I am a "+this.kind+".");
   }
}

print(typeof Machine.prototype); // causes a compile-time error
var c = new Machine(2);
c.announce(); // prints  "I am a car."
```